# rails 4 many to many through pivot table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My models:

```
class Entrant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events, :through => :event_maps
  has_many :event_maps, :foreign_key  => "entrant_id"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :events, :reject_if => :all_blank
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :event_maps, :foreign_key => "event_id"
  has_many :entrants, :through => :event_maps
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :entrants, :reject_if => :all_blank
end

class EventMap < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event, foreign_key: "event_id"  
  belongs_to :entrant, foreign_key: "entrant_id" 
end
```

My mappings are correct as far as I can tell, on the console I can do following:

create a new event and add a new entrant:

```
@event = Event.new(name: 'my event');
@event.save
@event.entrants_attributes = [{name: 'Jack'}]
@event.save
```

create a new entrant and add a new event:

```
@entrant = Entrant.new(name: 'Peter')
@entrant.save
@entrant.events_attributes = [{name: 'Great concert'}]
@entrant.save
```

Now how would I map `Peter` to `my event` or `Jack` to `Great concert`?
**Meaning**

1. I want to register an existing Entrant to an existing Event,
2. Add a new Entrant to an existing Event or vice versa.

As I said, the many 2 many seems to work both ways, but adding data to the pivot table on existing objects is not really clear to me. Thanks for the help.

**Edit: ok I got 2.**

```
@event.entrants.new(name: "hello") #adds a new Entrant works
```

Comment: `@event.entrants << @entrant` is what you're looking for. Go get some book or read some materials online… http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ http://railscasts.com/ http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Comment: Perfect that works ... What does << do? I am sure it adds the data in the pivot, but what does it mean in ruby terms?

Comment: j03w I am doing all of the above :-) hanging out on railscast is a daily and I have done 80% of the rails tutorial :D

Comment: j03w add an answer and I will accept

Comment: Probably you need to do more reading. Keep it up mate.

Comment: There is lots to learn for the little padawan ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do (as j03w suggested)

```
   @event.entrants << @entrant
```

The << is the Binary Left Shift Operator which

> Binary Left Shift Operator. The left operands value is moved left by
>   the number of bits specified by the right operand.

It's also used for arrays to push the given object on to the end of this array. This expression returns the array itself, so several appends may be chained together.

```
  $: [] << 'a'
  -> ['a']
```